# Is saving rasters to VRT bad convention?

Tags: gdal, vrt

I'm working with a lot of rasters (dozens of thousands) and would like to store them for a while. They will be used intermittently, but never all at once! The size of VRT (~2 kb) is such a positive for me, because I can store a year's worth of rasters with less than a GB for cost, whereas before I was dealing with upwards of 50 GB when using TIF.

I'm just worried that maybe I don't fully understand the VRT file type. I've tried to look at documentation and don't see anything wrong with doing this.

Do you think this is OK?

Comment: VRT itself is not a raster but it gives instructions about how to read the real image file. I suppose that you know that and if you take care that you save the original data files together with the .vrt files there is nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I know the VRT itself is not a raster, but can be easily converted to one using gdal_translate. Based on your response, I have to keep the original .tif alongside the .vrt in order for the .vrt to be functional? Sorry, just trying to make sure I understand.

Comment: Yes, you have to keep the original .tif available. VRT is described in https://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html and you can read there how it works `<SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">utm.tif</SourceFilename>`.

Comment: @user30184 - please make this an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, this does not make sense.**

VRT is **Virtual** Raster Type, not a **real** raster. There is no data in a VRT, the data is just referenced in an XML file. You have to keep the original data.

```
<SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">utm.tif</SourceFilename>
```

[See here](https://gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) for documentation.

VRT's make sense for e.g. mosaicing, merging, cutting, converting files when you don't want to store the result but do it on the fly; or have the VRT as intermediate product to a further converstion.

> a virtual dataset [...] composed from other [...] datasets with repositioning, and algorithms **potentially** applied as well as various kinds of metadata altered or added.

**You can create VRTs of your TIFs, but that is just extra space.**

To reduce file size, you might [use compression](https://kokoalberti.com/articles/geotiff-compression-optimization-guide/) on the files if they are not already compressed. Lossless compression (Deflate, LZW, Packbits) will reduce the size by a fair amount, [lossy compression (JPEG)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/246858/87998) if possible will reduce by a huge amount.

Comment: It may make sense to save the .vrt files if the original images must be saved in any case, and if .vrt adds something non-trivial to the original data that normally requires writing out a new physical image file. For example derived bands and pansharpened VRT in https://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html are good examples about that.

Comment: that is what I tried to say in the second paragraph "VRT's make sense for ..."

Comment: One other use is sparse raster. That is several non contiguous rasters that can be used as a whole without having to store a full raster encompassing them

Comment: This works as long as you still work in the same CRS. If your project is in another CRS, reprojecting the source data of the VRT on-the-fly will cost a reasonable time during project work, compared to a ready-reprojected new TIF file. Same goes for low-zoom overviews if your source data does not have them.

Comment: Thank you so much - I had gotten lost in the VRT documentation. I will just stick with compression!